# How to remove duplicate value from array?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this in array:

```
[
    {item: "7621629-01/17-23", phoneNum: "032/406713"},
    {item: "7621629-01/17-24", phoneNum: "032/406713"},
    {item: "7621629-01/17-25", phoneNum: "032/406713"}
]
```

What i want is to remove all duplicates phoneNum and left only one. Any suggestion how can i do that? Its in .ts file. So to have object but to remove duplicate phoneNum because im using autocomplete and now in suggestion i get three same number

Comment: this is not array of objects and i dont want to use jquery

Comment: From the existing array, create a new array that doesn't have duplicates.

Comment: @uzhas at that question sort by votes, you will find lots of solutions. Using Jquery, filter, etc.. If you don't like them just use a loop. And what you are showing are 3 objects.....

Answer (score -1):

try to use a pipe like this

```
transform(items: Array<any>, args?: any): any {

        let filtredItems= [];

        if(Array.isArray(items) && items.length > 0)
          items.forEach((el) => { 
             if(filtredItems.indexOf(el) < 0) 
                filtredItems.push(el)  
          });

        return filtredItems;
}
```